# What are the Arithmetic Data Types in Swift?

Tags: swift, swift3

I recently read that `Enums` and `tuples` have mathematical structure and they are known as the sum and product types respectively, similar to arithmetic.

I can understand that enums are `sum` type but not able understand tuple as a product type.

```
  enum Add<T, U> {
     case left(T)
     case right(U)
  }
```

So, if `U` has three members and `T` has five then `Add<T, U>` will have 8 but I am not able to come up with an example of product types.

Also,

1. Is enum can also behave as product types?
2. How are arithmetic data types useful?

Answer (score 0):

Enum represents the either situation - the value can be one of the cases. It is like an alternative known as logical sum. I don't think they can be considered product types.

Tuple represents a situation when you obtain all values - it is an element of a set that is a carthesian product of the domains of each element contained by tuple. That is why you can think of them as a product types. So given the asumptions you made for the enum case a tuple like '(T, U)' will have 15 possible variants as each of the T can be combined with each of the U - 3*5 = 15

Comment: I haven't made an assumption. `Enums` can be of product types [link](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=LP9vDQAAQBAJ&pg=PA92&lpg=PA92&dq=swift++enum+arithmetic+datatype&source=bl&ots=7IpV-FCq3I&sig=BrwFEgNCIbSdeup2Ok0Or7tFMXw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjA2OfGksTTAhXFKY8KHT1xD48Q6AEIRzAG#v=onepage&q=swift%20%20enum%20arithmetic%20datatype&f=false). So the question here remains, `What is arithmetic data type?` and how it can be useful.

Answer (score -1):

**Simple Example of "enum" in swift 3.0**

```
enum names 
{
   case Swift
   case Closures
}

var lang = names.Closures // Call .Closures case 
lang = .Closures

switch lang 
{
   case .Swift:
   print("Welcome to Swift")

   case .Closures:   //call this case
   print("Welcome to Closures")

   default:
   print("Introduction")
}
```

Output:    Welcome to Closures

**Example-2:**

```
enum Climate 
{
   case India
   case America
   case Africa
   case Australia
}

var season = Climate.America // call .America case
season = .America

switch season 
{
   case .India:
      print("Climate is Hot")
   case .America:
      print("Climate is Cold") // call this case
   case .Africa:
      print("Climate is Moderate")
   case .Australia:
      print("Climate is Rainy")
   default:
      print("Climate is not predictable")
}
```

Output: Climate is Cold

Comment: This does not even remotely answer the question.  This is just an example of how to use an enum.